# Facebook SSOw Login and Posting Image not working.

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

I will try and be as in-depth as possible. I followed the guide on the Facebook dev site and ended up with this code:

in my AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
...    
Facebook *facebook;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
```

In the AppDelegate implementation I have specified the facebook appid etc.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *menuView = self.menuViewController.view;

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"172938549507285" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }
    ... 
}
```

and just incase my app was never closed I have implemented the same method in:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{   

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"172938549507285" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
            NSLog(@"Facebook session is not valid");
    }
    NSLog(@"Application Entering Foreground.. setting segue to login flag");
    [defaults setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"shouldgotologin"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

However even after implementing all this I never get the facebook login window open... It just never comes up... it came up once before... But I now never see anything in my console log.... I dont really know why... I am very lost. can someone help me? Please dont direct me to the Facebook dev site... that is where I just came from thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the code.

As Chris said, you are now logged in.

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {

}

put an else block here to give confirmation that you are alreadly logged in or perhaps move on to the next viewcontroller.

Comment: OK thanks. It was the accessToken that expired so I extended it and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a  stupid question, but you say that you only saw it once... are you sure you're not just logged in now?

If you uninstall and re-install the App do you see it again?